# Using OCR (pytesser) on C-SPAN with mixed results

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr, tesseract

I'm playing around with pytesser to extract voting information off of C-SPAN, but I am pretty much an OCR newb.

I am starting with a single screenshot for now. I first turned the image black and white, inverted the colors, then maximized the contrast. The following links to the before and after image processing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlvBz.jpg

Now I run pytesser:

```
from pytesser import *
image = Image.open('cspantest1.tif')  # Open image object using PIL
print image_to_string(image)     # Run tesseract.exe on image
```

With mixed results:

```
ON BROUN O~F~GE0R~GIA'T.;,v I
MOTION TO INSTRUCT  
CONFEREES ; ij h;~J I
~   I       IF
I II, [I; I
H n Iaaae
I I I I` 4*4
, '   I *~ -'~YEA ^-NWY,PRE5 NV
RERUBLICAN I; 82 145  15. II
DEM`OC~F}7\EpF "` ;`1~78-V 4~ ~*v12
_;'~ INDEPENDENT S! It I 2
~YI`a.a:1i- > *-},,5
TOTAL`S 82 323   27
TIME REMAINING 0:00 ..
"W.. .. g I
. "f'    z-;A         
I .
```

The key data is there, all the numbers, and the timer, but I figure there must be a better way to do it. Build a library of each individual character for the training file? Limit the scope of allowed characters?

Ultimately, I'd like to automate the entire image manipulation and OCR process. If anyone has tips for cleaning this up, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: To limit the scope of allowed characters you got to set tessedit_char_whitelist configuration variable. Not sure how to do this in pytesser though.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up leaving pytesser behind for the time being, and am just using the command line functionality. I'm getting pretty good results off of image processing (especially dilating after contrasting and grayscaling). The big issue now is single character recognition. The white list stuff I find often just forces recognition of noise as numbers and generally doesn't help because it makes it harder to filter out crap afterward.